# Subplots except Value Error: Invalid syntax

Tags: python, while-loop, syntax-error, subplot, except

I know that there are some answers for this question, but unfortunately I couldn't make any of them work.
I have a loop that plots certain time intervals as subplots, but some time intervals due the cleaning of the data get deleted. Now I would like to skip that time interval and just continue normally.

I tried to do that with:

```
    except ValueError:
        continue
```

But I get invalid syntax error.

Original code:

```
dimenzion = math.ceil(np.sqrt(len(lista_start)))

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=dimenzion,ncols=dimenzion, figsize=(25, 21), sharex=False)
sns.despine(left= True)
fig.suptitle('Clean data', y =1.01, fontsize = 21)


date = 0
i = 0
j = 0
while date <= len(lista_end)-1:
   df_date = df_clean[(df_clean['Time'] > pd.Timestamp(lista_start.loc[date][0])) & 
                      (df_clean['Time'] < pd.Timestamp(lista_end.loc[date][0]))]
   
   df_date = df_date.reset_index(drop = True)
 
   start = datetime.datetime.strftime(lista_start.loc[date][0], '%d.%m.%y')
   end = datetime.datetime.strftime(lista_end.loc[date][0], '%d.%m.%y')
   
   df_date.plot('Time', 'Mids Ply Fines B', figsize = (25,7), ax = axes[i,j], subplots = True)
   axes[i,j].set_title('{} - {}'.format(start, end))
   axes[i,j].get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
   
    
   j = j+1
   date = date + 1
   
   if j > dimenzion - 1:
       j = 0
       i = i+1  
           
   except ValueError:
       continue
   
   plt.setp(axes, yticks=[])
   plt.tight_layout()
```

Comment: `except` is only meaningful after a `try`.

Comment: Probably better to test if df_date has the prober value than to rely on failure of the plot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Python, the except needs a starting try - you need to tell it which code 'section' might generate the error you want to capture :

I don't know what line is generating the ValueError - but this should be sufficient:

```
   try : 
      df_date = df_clean[(df_clean['Time'] > pd.Timestamp(lista_start.loc[date][0])) & 
                  (df_clean['Time'] < pd.Timestamp(lista_end.loc[date][0]))]

     df_date = df_date.reset_index(drop = True)

     start = datetime.datetime.strftime(lista_start.loc[date][0], '%d.%m.%y')
     end = datetime.datetime.strftime(lista_end.loc[date][0], '%d.%m.%y')

     df_date.plot('Time', 'Mids Ply Fines B', figsize = (25,7), ax = axes[i,j], subplots = True)
     axes[i,j].set_title('{} - {}'.format(start, end))
     axes[i,j].get_xaxis().set_visible(False)

     j = j+1
     date = date + 1

     if j > dimenzion - 1:
         j = 0
     i = i+1  
       
   except ValueError:
      continue
```

Notice who the whole code 'section' between the try and the except are indented - that makes it clear that any ValueError exception generated anywhere in that section will result in the continue being created.

Comment: Hi, thank you. It is not showing me an error any more, but now it doesn't plot, it just gets stuck in execution. Do you have any ideas why?

Comment: @bassline_ballerina - can you remember which line gave the original error ?

Comment: `
File "<ipython-input-13-9420515ee56d>", line 32
    except ValueError:
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
`

Comment: yes - that was the eaw 'except' error (without the try) ...

I mean without the try and except what generates the ValueError ... That might help identify why you are getting a blank plot ..

Comment: Aha, sorry for that. I am analysing production. We are producing product A,B,C,D. We produce every product at different time. If my data set would contain all of the products it would be continuous time wise. When I select product A I have time chucks (table with the start and end dates). When I clean the data some of those time chunks get deleted.and when the code looks at the start and the end time it doesn't have any data to plot. I would like it to skip those time periods.

Comment: I'm sorry, if you look at the code there is lista_start and lista_end that is pandas dataset with the start and end dates.

Comment: how do you identify that a time-period has no data ?

Comment: I see it in the dataset when I manually look for the dates

Comment: @bassline_ballerina can you actually define in terms of speciffic conditions what is 'missing data' ?

Comment: There is actually no data. on Monday our production was 15, on Wednesday was 10, on Friday was 5, and on Sunday was 17. Then I say that I am interested only in production that is above 9. Then on Friday I have blank and when loops comes to Friday it gives an ValueError and doesn't plot Sunday.

Comment: @bassline_ballerina can you iterate through the data and actually remove the invalud data, or set the Missing data to zero ?